# How can the loop integral of the magnetic vector potential, for a loop enclosing a toroidal inductor but outside of it, equal the nonzero flux inside?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm stuck on an apparent contradiction and I can't find any explanation of my specific difficulty:
[image: A-lines are the magnetic vector potential]
In a perfect toroidal inductor with constant current running through the windings, there is a magnetic field and flux within the toroid but no magnetic field outside of it. The magnetic field equals the curl of the magnetic vector potential A, and therefore everywhere outside the toroid the curl of A equals zero. But as a result, any closed line integral of A equals zero. How then can the line integral of a loop which encloses the toroid through the donut hole (like the A-lines in the picture) equal the flux inside the toroid? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "there is a magnetic field and flux within the toroid but no magnetic field outside of it." is wrong.  Use Ampere's law.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin  your confusing the direction of current

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I got careless.

Answer (score -1):

$\iint \vec{B} \cdot \vec{da}$

Substituting : ($\vec{B} = \nabla × \vec{A}$)

=
$\iint (\nabla × \vec{A}) \cdot \vec{da}$

Applying stokes theorem,

$\oint \vec{A} \cdot \vec{dl}$

So the flux of B is related to the closed line integral of A,

$\vec{B}=0$ does not imply $\vec{A}=0$

B is non zero inside the toroid, and thus any closed line integral with an area enclosing the inside, is non zero.

Comment: To downvoter. I'm curious why the downvoted? Is there something wrong with this answer?